# MVC Entity Framework calling stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.5 and EF. I import the stored procedures into my ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I have my `.edmx` and `XX.tt` with my `StoreProcedure_Result.cs`.

I use

```
var result = dbcontext.SP(Param).AsEnumerable().First();
```

My problem is that those stored procedures that have

```
select count(id) as Count from table
```

doesn't appear on my `SP_Result.cs`

Any ideas?

Comment: I would open the .edmx file and "Update Model from Database" and make sure that the stored procedure in question is selected to add or refresh.

Comment: I did that. My Stored Procedure appears on my .edmx, but it does not appear on my _Result.cs... Furthermore, if I change it, and put "select id from table" instead of "select count(id) from table".. it appears on my _results.cs. It seems it does not like "count()" syntax..

Comment: Did you try calling stored procedure anyway? A "_Result.cs" class might not be created in these cases because it would just be a int. EF might not bother creating a dedicated type just to represent an int. That is my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out myself and did not see a "_Result.cs" class created either for the sproc that just returns count(). I'm guessing that a _Result.cs class does not need to be created because it is just a single int, and a specific type is not needed. I was still able to call the sproc though. You could obtain the int like this...

```
var result = db.getCount().First(); 
int i = (int)result;
```

Comment: OK, but in that case, when i call "var result = dbcontext.SP(Param).AsEnumerable().First();"  where do i get the result count() from the SP.?

Comment: This works fine for me...

            var result = db.getCount().First();
            int i = (int)result;